# Mysql stored function help needed

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Can i pass a sql where condition string as a param to a SP and execute it inside? I would like to return the no. of rows inserted as well... but why its not working?

phpmyadmin says .. `**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WhereCond;**`

```
 DELIMITER //
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS ExecSQL //
    CREATE FUNCTION ExecSQL(WhereCond text) RETURNS INT DETERMINISTIC
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO myTable WhereCond;

        return ROW_COUNT();
    END //
```

My WhereCond in php is

```
$WhereCond = " (ID, Name) VALUES (556, 'Suraj')";
```

I'm just playing with SPs, so dont mind if these questions sound like stupid

Answer (score 1):

It is not working because you can't pass a part of sql query as argument for the stored function.

What you try to do here is:

```
INSERT INTO myTable "(ID, Name) VALUES (556, 'Suraj')";
```

which obviously is not a valid sql query.